# magento tracking pixel

Tags: magento, tracking

There are two variables which are required in the tracking pixel which needs to be placed on category, product info, cart and confirmation page.

I've managed to get the Prod list and Prod working, however, the second two are causing me problems.

I can echo out the sku in the cart, however, the products are configurable products so it's duplicating the sku in the output. The code I'm using is below:

```
<?php
// $items = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();foreach($items as $item) { echo ''.$item->getSku().'&nbsp;';}
?>
```

How do i change this to just display the one configurable SKU?

The second element is the Category name that the product exists in, Any one got any ideas on that? I've tried multiple variations but they've either broke the page or returned nothing.

Any help would be appreciated. If someone could also give me examples of how these would work on the confirmation page as well, that would be great.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the products visibility (simple products attached to a configurable would not be visible):

```
$items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach($items as $item) {
    if ($item->getProduct()->isVisibleInSiteVisibility()) {
        echo ''.$item->getSku().'&nbsp;';
    }
}
```

With regards to the category name, a product can appear in multiple categories so im not sure how you want to handle that.  Also, there is a concern that you are beginning to duplicate code across several template files.  You will want to consider moving this all out to a block.

Anyway, to get the category names that the product belongs to here is at least one method of doing this...

```
$categoryCollection = $item->getProduct()->getCategoryCollection()
                            ->addAttributeToSelect('name');

    foreach($categoryCollection as $category) {
       echo $category->getData('name') . "<br/>";
    }
```